# Probability and Expectation

Tags: probability

A box of 100 tickets contains 45 red tickets, 50 blue tickets and 5 yellow tickets 20 tickets will be drawn from this box at random, without replacement.

We will draw 20 tickets at random without replacement. If there is at least one yellow ticket in our sample, we will stop. What is the probability that we will see a sample with at least one yellow ticket for the first time on the third try? What is our expected number of tries?

The solution given is 0.0694

I'm having a lot of trouble to even getting started with this problem.

what I got so far is P(1st not yellow) x P(2nd not yellow) x P(3rd is a yellow) =$\frac {\binom {95}{20}}{\binom {100}{20}}$ $\cdot$ $\frac {\binom {94}{19}}{\binom {100}{20}}$ $\cdot$ (1-$\frac {\binom {95}{20}}{\binom {100}{20}}$)

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: So let me get this straight... we initially have 100 tickets., we draw twenty of them and we check to see if there is a  yellow.  If there isn't a yellow, then we take the remaining 80 tickets and draw twenty from those and check if there is a yellow?  If still no, then we draw from the remaining 60 tickets, etc...?  And we are asking for the probability that there was no yellow within the first two batches of twenty and there is a yellow within the third batch of twenty which came from the attempt where we were pulling from 60?  Or, are we drawing from the original 100 tickets each attempt?

Comment: oh sorry let me clarify: if there isn't at least one yellow ticket  in our sample then  we put the tickets back into the box shuffle again and randomly draw the tickets again.

Comment: Okay.  Your attempt then is incredibly close... but you have done something strange to your second numerator.

Comment: As for calculating the expected number of tries, by treating this as a geometric distribution, the result is well known.  Given a probability $p$ of success per attempt and the attempts results are independent of one another, the expected number of attempts until the first success is simply $\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz should the second term be $\frac {\binom {94}{19}}{\binom {99}{19}}$ Since this question is saying without replacement and since the first ball we are assuming it's not yellow then it's taken out of the total pool?

Comment: I interpret "attempts" and "tries" here to be in reference to having taken twenty balls., not single balls at a time.  That is to say, I interpret the question to be asking for P(1st batch contains no yellows) x P(2nd batch contains no yellows) x P(3rd batch contains at least one yellow)

Comment: @JMoravitz oh yea! that makes sense! then the second term is the same as the first. I think I got it now! thank you for the clarification!